# CSS drop down menu - stack order not right?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, z-index

Our test server is here:

http://208.43.52.30/event/list

See on the top right the box that says "Organizers" ..

For some reason I can't get the drop down to come on the top layer ... I've tried changing positioning, I've tried changing z-index, but no luck ..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `div.header-holder` has `overflow: hidden`, if you change that then the organizers list should show without any trouble.

---

**Edited** in response to OP's comment:

> They are actually being covered up by those images now, and those don't have overflow:hidden applied...

You might find that applying `position:absolute;` to the drop-down `ul` (and `position: relative` to its parent `li`) should resolve that, by taking it out of the regular document flow, and making it sit above other non-`absolute` elements.

Of course since 'those' images are part of a carousel/slideshow, and positioned `absolute` too, they might not *natively* show 'above' them. In this case it's worth specifying a `z-index` for the slideshow images, and making sure that the `z-index` of the drop-down is higher than that for the images.

Comment: They are actually being covered up by those images now, and those don't have overflow:hidden applied...

Comment: It's always worth using Chrome's web inspector, or Firefox's Firebug add on to show what styles are being applied, and where they're coming from. Plus, in this instance, because of *where* it was being clipped both I, and probably @Matt, figured that `overflow` was the likeliest culprit.

Comment: Cool - did you see my follow up? It still doesn't clear those images, which don't have the overflow property...

Comment: just saw your last response .. let me go check

Comment: @Kevin, see the newer edit, the slideshow's also `position: absolute` (and appear later in the DOM), so you'll need to use `z-index` as well.

Comment: now those images do have a z-index - 

#visual-box img
{
    position:absolute;
 display:block;
 z-index:8;
}

#visual-box IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
}

#visual-box IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;

Comment: The dropdown z-index is also set:

ul.dropdown {
 padding-bottom: 1px;
 font: bold 13px/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 z-index: 1;
   border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #f0f0f0 #666 #666 #f0f0f0;
}

Comment: @Kevin, if you make sure the drop-down's `z-index` is greater (I tend to use a large amount, just to be sure) than that of the slideshow it should work. I'd recommend a `z-index: 9999;` just for kicks and surety =)

Comment: @Kevin, why thank you, kind sir =b And also for the accept =)

Answer (score 1):

On your `div` element with ID "header-holder", you have CSS `overflow` values of `hidden`.  Since the organizers list is a child of that, it won't be displayed outside of the bounds of that `div`.  Get rid of those, and you're fine.

Comment: did that - worked great, however it doesn't display past the images now .. which don't have the overflow:hidden rule..

Answer (score 0):

In the css block for #visual-box change the z-index to 0 and in the block for .header-holder change z-index to 1 and overflow to visable

Answer (score 0):

You need to make tweaks to various values. Add these CSS rules:

```
.header-holder { overflow: visible; z-index: 300; }
#visual-box { z-index: 300; }
.box-info { z-index: 301; }
.box-info ul.dropdown { z-index: 301; }
```